# How to convert date format in Rstudio

Tags: r, date, dplyr, lubridate

I'm a beginner with Rstudio and I ran into one problem. I work with a time series that has date format written as follows:

```
2015-01-01
2015-02-01
2015-03-01
2015-04-01
2015-05-01
2015-06-01
2015-07-01
2015-08-01
2015-09-01
2015-10-01
2015-11-01
2015-12-01
```

I had to change it with this:

```
dplyr::mutate(TimeSeries,
      year = lubridate::decimal_date(time),
      month= lubridate::month(time, label = T),
      month = factor(month, ordered=F))
```

And now, my data has date format like this:

```
2015.000
2015.085
2015.162  
2015.247 
2015.329 
2015.414
2015.496 
2015.581 
2015.666 
2015.748 
2015.833 
2015.915
```

My problem is, that I need to work with this format, but I need to know number of month. I cant do just modulo, because of small changes in decimal places in each year. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I have adpated your tags. Please provide a [minimal repdroducible example] https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example in order to get adequate support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `label` argument from `lubridate::month` and then you don't need to use `factor(month, ordered=F)` unless you need this value as a factor:

```
dplyr::mutate(TimeSeries,
              year = lubridate::decimal_date(time),
              month= lubridate::month(time))
```

**Output**

```
         time     year month
1  2015-01-01 2015.000     1
2  2015-02-01 2015.085     2
3  2015-03-01 2015.162     3
4  2015-04-01 2015.247     4
5  2015-05-01 2015.329     5
6  2015-06-01 2015.414     6
7  2015-07-01 2015.496     7
8  2015-08-01 2015.581     8
9  2015-09-01 2015.666     9
10 2015-10-01 2015.748    10
11 2015-11-01 2015.833    11
12 2015-12-01 2015.915    12
```

---

**Data**

```
TimeSeries <- structure(list(time = structure(c(16436, 16467, 16495, 16526, 
16556, 16587, 16617, 16648, 16679, 16709, 16740, 16770), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```